# Highlight selected TELERIK MVC GRID row text in BOLD

Tags: model-view-controller, grid, telerik

I have a Telerik MVC Grid where I have a column as " select " , " edit" forwhich I have used Format Property to show Links to my ActionMethods . Now I want to show the selected Row text in Bold when someone clicks on " Select" / " Edit " link ?

How to achieve this using JQuery / Javascript ? Tried using RowAction but couldnt sort out this as I am using Format Property and Ajax.ActionLink for Select and Edit ActionLinks.

```
    <% Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.GetLegends)
                    .Name("PaymentScheduleLegendGrid")

                    .ToolBar(toolBar => toolBar.Template(() =>
                                  { 
                            %>
                                 <label style="height:10px; float:left;padding-right:230px;" >Legend</label>

                                  <%= Ajax.ActionLink("Add", "AddLegend", "PaymentSchedule", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "updateTarget", UpdateTargetId = "addlegend", HttpMethod = "Get" }, new { Style="text-decoration:underline;" })%>

                                 <% 
                        })).HtmlAttributes("style='background:none grey'")
                    .DataKeys(dataKeys => dataKeys.Add(m => m.LegendId))                        
                    .Columns(columns =>
                        {

                           // columns.Bound(m => m.Legend_color).ClientTemplate("<div><div style='float:right;text-align:left;width:80%'><#= legend_name #></div>" + "<div style='padding:3px;background-color:<#= legend_color #>;width:20px;height:15px'></div></div>").Title("Legend");
                            columns.Bound(m => m.LegendColor).Format(Html.ColorBlock("{0}").ToHtmlString()).Encoded(false).Title("");
                            columns.Bound(m => m.LegendId).Hidden(true).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "newBack" }); ;
                            columns.Bound(m => m.LegendName).Title("");
                            columns.Bound(m => m.LegendId).Title("").Format(Ajax.ActionLink("Select", "Select", "PaymentSchedule", new { Id = "{0}" }, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "updateTarget", UpdateTargetId = "AddPaymentSchedule", HttpMethod = "Get" }, new { Style = "text-decoration:underline;" }).ToHtmlString().Replace("{", "{{").Replace("}", "}}")).Encoded(false).Width(60);
                            columns.Bound(m => m.LegendId).Title("").Format(Ajax.ActionLink("Edit", "EditLegend", "PaymentSchedule", new { Id = "{0}" }, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "updateTarget", UpdateTargetId = "addlegend", HttpMethod = "Get" }, new { Style = "text-decoration:underline;" }).ToHtmlString().Replace("{", "{{").Replace("}", "}}")).Encoded(false).Width(60);                             
                        })
                     //   .RowAction(row => row.Selected = row.HtmlAttributes.Add("style", "background:#321211;"))
                        .Sortable()
                        .Selectable().HtmlAttributes("style=font:bold")
                        .DataBinding(databinding => databinding
                        .Ajax().Select("AjaxIndex", "Legend"))
                        .Pageable(pager => pager.PageSize(5))
                        .Render();                 
 %>
```

This is my code and When user clicks on Select / Edit  ActionLink ... Selected LegendName should be highlighted in bold . When I use Selectable property I am getting the selected row as highlighted ( new Background color for selected row which doesnt satisfy my requirement). Besides that I have one more requirement , I want to change the background color of my toolbar to GREY . Can you please help me

Comment: It is not clear what your setup is. Please post some code.

Comment: Still I didnt get any answer . Atanas Korchev , arent you Telerik MVC Guy who normally answers all questions on telerik Forums . I have posted my question in telerik Forums also but i havent got any answers yet . Please help its very urgent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to apply certain style for certain table row you need to use CSS. For server side binding you can use the HtmlAttributes from RowAction. However I don't know (as you haven't described) how to determine if a row is selected inside the RowAction method. If you want a more concrete answer I suggest you attach a running project which shows the entire scenario in the forum thread which you opened in the Telerik forums.

If you want to do that client-side you can use jQuery:

```
<%: Html.Telerik().Grid().ClientEvents(e => e.OnLoad("onLoad")) %>

<script>
function onLoad() {
   $(this).delegate("tr a", "click", function(e){
       $(this).closest("tr").addClass("t-state-selected") // add the css class
                            .siblings()
                            .removeClass("t-state-selected") // remove css class from other rows
   });
}
</script>
```

Comment: If someone clicks on " Select" Link , I want to set " LegendName" in Bold or instead of this I want to set all text to be bold , of that particular row. forget about the Selected Row action . I just want to set my text in bold when someone clicks on that particular link .

Comment: I am afraid I cannot help you further. I still can't understand what your requirement is and what problems you are facing.

Comment: Atanas Korchev  Your solution to my problem is working but the problem is text in another column of my Grid  doesnt remain as bold once my partial view is opened it changes back to normal . Besides that once i navigate to last row ( i have 100s of rows and my Grid is pagable ) and click on my link my partial view is opened but my Grid is again rebound and i lost my highlighted Row . Here i start facing new problems . Here if I again click on any link then Text is highlighted but I am not able to open my partial view and highlighted row remains as it is

Comment: Please Help me Buddy . You are the only source for help regarding Telerik MVC Products

Comment: I have updated my reply to clear the CSS class from the other row.

Comment: Still no Luck ... I am not  able to clear CSS from other row at the first time once my page is loaded .. but when I go to other rows using the Paging arrows and click on my link then only your code starts applying but before that it doesn't work .. I want it to work all the time .. i.e. once my page is loaded and when I start paging my rows at that time also @ Atanas Korchev

Comment: I tested my code locally and it works as expected. I can't tell why it does not work in your case. I suggest you open a forum thread in the telerik mvc forums and attach a sample project there. I can't help any further by guessing what went wrong.

Comment: I don't know either... What happened with sending a project in the Telerik forums? I can't help further without a working sample...

Comment: I am unable to send you my project as it is an intellectual  property of my company . They will sue me ... :(.. By the way your answer was helpful for me ... There must be some problem with my JQuery Setup .. Anyways Thanks for your help and I am accepting your answer

Comment: Can't you create a simpler version with dummy data? Can't be that hard. I am not asking you to send your company IP.

Answer (score 0):

```
    So far I have done this .

<style type="text/css"> 
#PaymentScheduleLegendGrid table thead 
{ 

}
.newBack
{
background:none grey;
}
.newBoldtext
{
 font-weight:bold;
 color:red;
 }
 </style>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function onLoad() {

    $(this).delegate("tr a", "click", function (e) {
        $(this).closest("tr").addClass("newBoldtext"); // or any other CSS class
    });
   }
</script>

<div>
 <% Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.GetLegends)
                    .Name("PaymentScheduleLegendGrid")                       
                    .ToolBar(toolBar => toolBar.Template(() =>
                                  { 
                            %>
                                 <label style="height:10px; float:left;padding-right:230px;" >Legend</label>

                                  <%= Ajax.ActionLink("Add", "AddLegend", "PaymentSchedule", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "updateTarget", UpdateTargetId = "addlegend", HttpMethod = "Get" }, new { Style="text-decoration:underline;" })%>

                                 <% 
                        })).HtmlAttributes("style='background:none grey'")
                    .DataKeys(dataKeys => dataKeys.Add(m => m.LegendId))
                      .ClientEvents(e => e.OnLoad("onLoad"))                      
                    .Columns(columns =>
                        {


                            columns.Bound(m => m.LegendColor).Format(Html.ColorBlock("{0}").ToHtmlString()).Encoded(false).Title("");
                            columns.Bound(m => m.LegendId).Hidden(true).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "newBack" }); ;
                            columns.Bound(m => m.LegendName).Title("test");

                            columns.Bound(m => m.LegendId).Title("")
                                .Format(Ajax.ActionLink("Select", "Select", "PaymentSchedule",
                                                         new { Id = "{0}"}
                                                        , new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "updateTarget", UpdateTargetId = "AddPaymentSchedule", HttpMethod = "Get" }
                                                        , new { name = "SelectRow", Style = "text-decoration:underline;" }

                                                         ).ToHtmlString().Replace("{", "{{").Replace("}", "}}")).Encoded(false).Width(60);

                            columns.Bound(m => m.LegendId).Title("").Format(Ajax.ActionLink("Edit", "EditLegend", "PaymentSchedule", new { Id = "{0}" }, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "updateTarget", UpdateTargetId = "addlegend", HttpMethod = "Get" }, new { Style = "text-decoration:underline;" }).ToHtmlString().Replace("{", "{{").Replace("}", "}}")).Encoded(false).Width(60);                             
                        })

                        .Sortable()
                        .Selectable().HtmlAttributes("style=font:bold")
                        .DataBinding(databinding => databinding
                        .Ajax().Select("AjaxIndex", "Legend"))
                        .Pageable(pager => pager.PageSize(10))
                        .Render();                 
 %>
```